# AIX HMC Vswitch and VLAN collection

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, aix

I'm collecting the VLAN details for each VIO server and LPAR's from HMC. I would need to group those VLANs one Vwsitch as `VSWITCHName=VLANID`, separated by comma. But some VIO servers have 2 VSWITCHES. I would like to display the data on single line as i'm using for loop to collect the data.

```
LAB1:~> lshwres -m system-01 -r virtualio --rsubtype eth --level lpar --filter lpar_names=ABC1234 -F vswitch:port_vlan_id:addl_vlan_ids
ETHERNET0:64:
ETHERNET0:2215:52,64
ETHERNET0:3969:701,702,2152,2154
ETHERNET0:4001:

LAB1:~> lshwres -m system-01 -r virtualio --rsubtype eth --level lpar --filter lpar_names=ABCD4567 -F vswitch:port_vlan_id:addl_vlan_ids
ETHERNET1:55:
ETHERNET1:3971:51,53,55
ETHERNET1:3972:2151,2153,2155
ETHERNET1:4002:
hmclab:~> lshwres -m system-01 -r virtualio --rsubtype eth --level lpar --filter lpar_names=ABCD7890 -F vswitch:port_vlan_id:addl_vlan_ids
ETHERNET0:52:
ETHERNET0:2152:

LAB1:~> lshwres -m system-01 -r virtualio --rsubtype eth --level lpar --filter lpar_names=ABCD7869 -F vswitch:port_vlan_id:addl_vlan_ids
ETHERNET0:54:4001
ETHERNET0:3968:52,54
ETHERNET1:3969:701,702,2152,2154,5569
ETHERNET1:4002:
ETHERNET1:5001
```

Output Expected is: `ETHERNET0= 52,54,3968,etc & ETHERNET1=5001,3969.701,`etc

Comment: @Kusalananda - Need your inputs

Comment: I'd like to help but I don't understand the aix context. Could you complete your expected output, replacing the *etc*? Are you providing 4 separate examples, or are they supposed to be combined into one?

Comment: @meuh, Sorry if i confused you, I would like to group ETHERNET0  and ETHERNET1 VLAN's on same line

Answer (score 0):

If you want to join up the lines with the same ethernet number, and replace the `:` by a `,` then you can pipe the output into

```
awk -F: '
/ETHERNET/{ i = $1; v[i] = v[i] "," $2; if($3!="")v[i] = v[i] "," $3 }
END{  n = asorti(v,x)
      for(j=1;j<=n;j++){ i = x[j]; print i "=" substr(v[i],2) }
}'
```

This splits each line on `:`, uses the first field `ETHERNET0`  as an index into an associative array `v`, which collects fields 2 and 3 (if field 3 isn't empty). At the end of input, the keys (indices) of the array are sorted so we can start output with `ETHERNET0`, and for each key we print it and the collected fields, omitting the first character which is always an extra comma, since we always add it before field 2.

The result, treating each of your commands as independent, is:

```
ETHERNET0=64,2215,52,64,3969,701,702,2152,2154,4001

ETHERNET1=55,3971,51,53,55,3972,2151,2153,2155,4002

ETHERNET0=52,2152

ETHERNET0=54,4001,3968,52,54
ETHERNET1=3969,701,702,2152,2154,5569,4002,5001
```